# SQL query to calculate Throughput based "subtracting" two Select statements using Group By

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to formulate a SQL query to calculate the difference in the number of people "arriving" and "departing" grouped by City and Date.

```
TravelerID    ArrivalDate     DepartureDate         City
   1           2015-10-01        2015-10-03       New York
   2           2015-10-02        2015-10-03       New York
   3           2015-10-02        2015-10-04       Chicago
   4           2015-10-01        2015-10-02       Chicago
```

I'm hoping to get a table that looks like

```
NumOfTravelers     Date        City
     1           2015-10-01    New York
     1           2015-10-02    New York
     -2          2015-10-03    New York
     1           2015-10-01    Chicago
     0           2015-10-02    Chicago
     -1          2015-10-04    Chicago
```

A positive number for NumOfTravelers means that more people arrived in that city on that particular date. A negative number for NumOfTravelers means that more people left that city on that particular date.

In trying to break down this SQL query, I've tried

```
SELECT COUNT(TravelerID) as NumTravelersArrivng, ArrivalDate, City FROM TravelTable GROUP BY ArrivalDate, City;


SELECT COUNT(TravelerID) as NumTravelersDeparting, DepartureDate, City FROM TravelTable GROUP BY DepartureDate, City;
```

I'm trying to get "NumTravelersArriving" - "NumTravelersDeparting" into a column that represents "traveler throughput" grouped by City and Date.

I've been so stumped on this. I'm using SQL Server, and having a frustrating time using Table aliases and Column aliases.

Comment: which db do you have? MySql and Sql Server are very different.

Comment: SQL Server. I'm using Microsft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Okay. Get the tags right next time. MySql doesn't support FULL JOIN, which is part of the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT City, ArrivalDate As Date, COUNT(TravelerID) As NumOfTravelers
    FROM TravelTable 
    GROUP BY City, ArrivalDate
) a
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT City, DepartureDate As Date, COUNT(TravelerID) * -1 As NumOfTravelers
    FROM TravelTable
    GROUP BY City, DepartureDate 
) b ON b.City = a.City AND b.Date = a.Date
```